# Show the only definable subsets of $ \langle \mathbb{Q} , < \rangle $are the empty set and $ \mathbb{Q} $

Tags: model-theory

I'm trying to show the above, and I know it should be quite simple, but I'm struggling to get my head around how you show subsets are not definable using automorphisms- so a detailed explanation would be appreciated- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $A\subseteq \Bbb Q$ is definable and $a\in A, b\notin A$. Then consider $\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q$, $x\mapsto x+b-a$.

Comment: OP asked for a detailed explanation, so adding a few details on why this does the job might be helpful.

Comment: So that map is an automorphism, but where does the contradiction come? Is it something about not preserving order?

Comment: @NaomiVides The point is that automorphisms preserve definable sets.

Comment: Ah got it- since a$ \mapsto $ b, that's the contraction. Thanks